# SSH to EC2 instance running in a private subnet in a VPC over VPN : connection timed out

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2

1. Created a VPC that is attached to VPN Tunnel. Made sure DNS Resolution and DNS Hostname to true
2. Created a subnet (private) with auto-assign public ip to true
3. Created Security Group that has inbound rule to allow SSH at port 22
4. Launched an Amazon Linux image using VPC (As defined in 1) and subnet (as defined in 2) and chose security group (as in 3) and existing key pair (for which I have the private key).
5. When I am trying to ssh to this instance using putty and entering public-ip ; I am getting connection refused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, it sounds like your network looks like this:

[image: Private subnet with VPN connection]
<sub>(source: [amazon.com](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/images/VPN_Basic_Diagram.png))</sub>

Things to consider:

- The **Auto-Assign Public IP Address** setting should only be assigned to public subnets, so turn it off.
- There is no need to assign a **Public IP address** since the instance is not connected to the Internet via an Internet Gateway. Instead, connect to the instance via its **Private IP address**.
- Ensure that the **Security Group** associated with the EC2 instance is permitting inbound SSH (port 22) traffic either from `Anywhere`, or from an IP address range that matches where you are coming from (on the other end of the VPN connection).
- **Ping is disabled by default** in Security Groups. To enable it, add `ICMP` from `Anywhere` in the Inbound rules.
- Confirm that it is a **Linux** instance (Windows does not support SSH)
- Convert the private keypair into a `PPK` file for use with PuTTY
- In **PuTTY**, select the PPK file under SSH/Auth
- Use a username of `ec2-user` when connecting to the server

Comment: THANK YOU so much.. It worked. The bad part was security group in my equation.

Answer (score 2):

Use the instance's private IP. Public IPs get routed as public traffic even if you're within the VPC.

Comment: Can you connect to the same machine from another EC2 instance within that VPC?

Comment: This is the first EC2 instance in that VPC.

Comment: I also tried to ping the public ips provided by AWS - timed out as well.

Comment: I do not want to add internet gateway.

Comment: Yeah ping wont work unless you open the ICMP port which is the protocol ping uses. You shouldn't need an internet gateway to connect within since it's all being routed on the private network. Of course, public ips won't work without an igw. I was suggesting launching a new EC2 instance so you can isolate whether it's an issue with your VPC or VPN. Seems as though it's the latter.